# How to issue token to user with specific roles only when using spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-authorization-server

I have users with 3 roles in my auth service: ADMIN, USER and USER_NOT_VERIFIED. I want spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server to issue tokens only to ADMIN and USER

Here is the original code that issues tokens to everyone

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(
            e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")
            )
    );
    return http.build();
}
```

I tried replacing `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);` with the following code. I get 401 when exchanging authorization code for tokens

```
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
        new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();
    http.securityMatcher(endpointsMatcher).authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
    ((AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl)authorize.anyRequest()).hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
}).csrf((csrf) -> {
    csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new RequestMatcher[]{endpointsMatcher});
}).apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @kratnu. I think this is a good question, so I wanted to take some time to answer it well. Sadly, my answer demonstrates a workaround for the time being, but it's super valuable to hear about use cases like this so we can be thinking about them if we haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

On the **token request** from the client, the request will be authenticated by the `RegisteredClient`'s `clientId` and `clientSecret` (e.g. client authentication). Since the requester is the client, it does not have `USER` or `ADMIN` roles and so your authorization rule `anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")` will not work for the token request, and result in an `AccessDeniedException`.

**NOTE:** You can enable trace logs (`logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`) and you will see "Access Denied" in the logs.

In addition, the [Authorization Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-authorization-endpoint) is not currently sitting behind Spring Security's `AuthorizationFilter`, which means rules like `anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")` won't affect the `authorization_code` flow either. This is because the validation of request parameters required by the spec should happen prior to authentication. Perhaps this setup could be revisited, if this is a common enough use case.

To work around this in the meantime, you can set up extra validation for the Authorization Request to mimic what would expect to happen in authorization rules. It's a bit more complex, but we can re-use the new `AuthorizationManager` implementation(s) in Spring Security to make this easier. Here's an example:

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        var authorizationServerConfigurer =
                http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class);
        var authenticationValidator =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationValidator()
                        .andThen(hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN"));

        authorizationServerConfigurer
            .authorizationEndpoint(withAuthenticationValidator(authenticationValidator))
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        // ...

        return http.build();
    }

    private static Customizer<OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointConfigurer> withAuthenticationValidator(Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext> authenticationValidator) {
        return authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint
                .authenticationProviders(authenticationProviders -> {
                    for (AuthenticationProvider ap : authenticationProviders) {
                        if (ap instanceof OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
                            authenticationProvider.setAuthenticationValidator(authenticationValidator);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private static Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext> hasAnyRole(String... roles) {
        var authenticated = AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated();
        var hasAnyRole = AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAnyRole(roles);
        return context -> {
            var authentication = context.getAuthentication();
            var principal = (Authentication) authentication.getPrincipal();

            // Skip validation check if user is not authenticated, since we expect the
            // Authorization Endpoint to perform this check and skip processing if the
            // user is not authenticated.
            if (!authenticated.check(() -> principal, context).isGranted()) {
                return;
            }

            // If the user is authenticated, reject request if user does not have the
            // necessary role(s).
            if (!hasAnyRole.check(() -> principal, context).isGranted()) {
                var cause = new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
                var error = new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.ACCESS_DENIED);
                throw new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationException(error, cause, context.getAuthentication());
            }
        };
    }
```

It's worth noting that the `OAuth2Error` of `access_denied` will have to be handled by the OAuth2 client, because this error will be given in a redirect back to the client. In the default sample, it just ends up with an infinite redirect because I haven't set up my example to handle this error.

See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-authorization-endpoint-customizing-authorization-request-validation) for more info on customizing validation for the Authorization Endpoint.